# Why is my x86 linked-list function throwing a segfault?

Tags: macos, assembly, return, stack, x86-64

I have been writing code high and low, all day long to try to get a linked list in x86 assembly. Nothing works, and it is so very frustrating. I am trying to make one that has elements 1, 2, and 3. GDB told me that it was segfaulting in the `ret` statement at `end`, but didn't provide any more info. Can anyone help me with this? I am assembling on a Mac with Clang.

Here is my code:

```
    .global _main
    .text

/*
r12: result
r14: number of elements left in list
r15: stack offset for accessing arguments
*/

make_list:
    # # # # #
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    # # # # #
    mov rdi, [rbp + r15]
    mov qword ptr [rax], rdi  # assign first_node.head
    lea r13, [rax + 8]  # store address of first_node.tail
    # # # # #
    mov rdi, 16
    sub rsp, 8
    call _malloc
    add rsp, 8
    # # # # #
    add r15, 8
    sub r14, 1
    # # # # #
    mov rdi, [rbp + r15]
    mov qword ptr [r13], rdi  # assign second_node.head
    # # # # #
    cmp r14, 0
    je end
    # # # # #
    mov rdi, 16
    sub rsp, 8
    call _malloc
    add rsp, 8
    # # # # #
    jmp make_list  # assign second_node.tail to an argument
    # # # # #
    end:
        mov qword ptr [r13 + 8], 0  # second_node.tail = NULL
        mov rsp, rbp
        pop rbp
        ret
    # # # # #

_main:
    # # # # #
    mov rdi, 16
    sub rsp, 8
    call _malloc
    add rsp, 8
    lea r12, [rax]
    # # # # #
    mov r14, 3
    mov r15, 16
    # # # # #
    push 3
    push 2
    push 1
    # # # # #
    call make_list
    add rsp, 24
    # # # # #
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall
    # # # # #
```

Comment: I've seen a number of your questions and wondering if you have considered using the `si` command in LLDB to step into your functions and stepping each of the instructions to see where things are failing. I think that learning to make the best use of your debugger LLDB would be your best bet in moving forward with your code generation.

Comment: @MichaelPetch This isn't generated code, I wrote this myself - this is for a standard library that I'm writing; also I'll check out LLDB thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jmp make_list` instruction is incorrect. You don't want to jump to the start of the function, where you much `rbp` again, but to somewhere partway in to your function, after all of your setup.

The multiple `push rbp` instructions that don't get popped before the `ret` cause the instruction pointer to get an invalid value in it, resulting in your setfault.

Comment: Thank you, that removed the segfault. I'm still not if my code works as intended yet but I'll let you know.